# ASCII Text not centering in Python

Tags: python

I got some ascii text but it's not centering, why?:

```
pray=text2art("Pray")
new_pray = pray.center(90)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"""{Fore.YELLOW}{new_pray}""")
```

It only works if it's not ASCII style text.

Comment: Maybe the `center` method is broken.

Comment: If this is being displayed in proportional text, multiple spaces may be collapsed.

Answer (score 1):

The `center` function aligns a single string in the space provided.  `text2art` converts one line to multiple lines.  `center` doesn't handle multiple lines.  Do the centering first, THEN call `text2art`.